# How to resolve java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jpa

I am using google app engine with JPA annotation;

I have one class

```
    @Entity
    public class XYZ implements Serializable{
    // default constructor and properties defined here.
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
public List<XYZ> listXYZ(String id) {
    List<XYZ> xyzlist = null;
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    try{
        // Read the existing entries
         Query q = em.createQuery("select t from XYZ t where t.id = :id");
         q.setParameter("id", id);
         xyzlist = q.getResultList();        
    }catch(Exception e){

    }finally{
        em.close();
    } 
  return xyzlist ;
}
```

I get list of objects from listXYZ() function.

```
  List<XYZ> list = dao.listXYZ("1");
```

but when I am going to put it into session

```
session.setAttribute("list",list);
```

It throws runtime exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery$1
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SerializableObjectsOnlyHashSessionManager$SerializableObjectsOnlyHttpSession.checkCanSerialize(SerializableObjectsOnlyHashSessionManager.java:64)
... 40 more
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the thing that your code is trying to serialize cannot be serialized.  (It could be a lazy list ... or they could simply have neglected to implement it as a serializable class.)

Assuming that the object in question is the one that you are assigning to `list`, the simple solution would be to copy it; e.g.

```
    session.setAttribute("list", new ArrayList<XYZ>(list));
```

(A `LinkedList` would work too, albeit with worse performance / greater memory usage.)

Answer (score 4):

Probably Query doesn't return a serializable list object from here :

Query q = em.createQuery("select t from XYZ t where t.id = :id");

q.setParameter("id", id);

```
     xyzlist = q.getResultList();  //
```

NOTE : you can convert the list as a ArrayList has implemented Serializable interface
ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: I did debug. Its returning the objects.

Comment: I am sure it did but the result must be serializable though. Could you share Query path ( import path ) ?